# How to convert String URL in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

Im having a big trouble with URl
I want to use url for almofire , but unforutnately it always return nil
or ortherwise , this solutuin return valid URL but with weird $$*%&$( in front of https:// an resulting to always got nil response

```
    let req = "​https://api-staging.xx.oo/v1/s-locations/"
    
    guard let percentReq = req.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed ) else { return nil }
    
    let urlReq = URL(string: percentReq)!
```

// work , url got , but fetch nothing

```
     let urlReq = URL(string: req)!
```

// error FATAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, looks like you managed to get some trash into the string by copy-pasting, I'm assuming it's encoding or something. This code from below works just fine:

```
let test = "https://api-staging.xx.oo/v1/s-locations/"
let url = URL(string: test)
```

Comment: Indeed, and VSCode doesn't seem to be able to render it. (even with Control and Whitespace characters enabled) That's weird.